# Splitting an os.date() table into multiple variables?

Tags: lua

I want to use os.date() to output the current full date so I can automatically input it into a converter to Warhammer's Imperial Date system.

At the moment I have os.date() outputting to a table but I have no idea how to actually set each individual value of it to a variable. Really I only need the year, month, and day, preferably as numbers and not spelled out. I planned to set them as global variables then toss them straight into my converter. How would I go about doing that?

Here's what I'm working with.

```
dtable = setmetatable(os.date('!*t'), {__call = function(self) self.tz=os.date('%z') self.ampam = os.date('%p') return self end})
dtable = dtable()
dir = function(tab) for k, v in pairs(tab) do print(k, '=>', v) end end
```

Comment: Can't you just do `year=dtable.year`, `month=dtable.month`, etc.? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @shingo I didn't know you could do that. I probably can, yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get more experience i suggest to play around with this...

```
dtable = setmetatable(os.date('*t', os.time({year = 1965, month = 8, day = 9, hour = 10, min = 45, sec = 33})), {__call = function(self) self.tz=os.date('%z') self.ampam = os.date('%p') return self end, __index = {dir = function(self) print(self) for key, val in pairs(self) do print(key, '=>', val) end end}})
```

...this adds the dir function as method.
Also you have to know that `ampam` depends on the locale...

```
> dtable = setmetatable(os.date('*t', os.time({year = 1965, month = 8, day = 9, hour = 10, min = 45, sec = 33})), {__call = function(self) self.tz=os.date('%z') self.ampam = os.date('%p') return self end, __index = {dir = function(self) print(self) for key, val in pairs(self) do print(key, '=>', val) end end}})
> os.setlocale('en_US.UTF8', 'time')
en_US.UTF8
> dtable():dir()
table: 0x566035c0
sec =>  33
min =>  45
hour    =>  10
ampam   =>  AM
year    =>  1965
day =>  9
isdst   =>  false
yday    =>  221
wday    =>  2
month   =>  8
tz  =>  +0100
> os.setlocale('de_DE.UTF8', 'time')
de_DE.UTF8
> dtable():dir()
table: 0x566047b0
sec =>  33
min =>  45
hour    =>  10
ampam   =>  
year    =>  1965
day =>  9
isdst   =>  false
yday    =>  221
wday    =>  2
month   =>  8
tz  =>  +0100
> os.setlocale('ja_JP.utf8', 'time')
ja_JP.utf8
> dtable:dir()
table: 0x565c1cc0
year    =>  1965
wday    =>  2
yday    =>  221
hour    =>  10
month   =>  8
min =>  45
isdst   =>  false
sec =>  33
day =>  9
> dtable():dir()
table: 0x565c1cc0
year    =>  1965
wday    =>  2
yday    =>  221
hour    =>  10
ampam   =>  午前
month   =>  8
tz  =>  +0100
min =>  45
isdst   =>  false
sec =>  33
day =>  9
```

(On Linux bash i getting the locale strings with: `locale -a`)
...and OS and Lua Version (maybe) in this case:

```
> os.execute('uname -a')
Linux Microknoppix 5.2.5-64 #10 SMP PREEMPT Sat Aug 3 20:57:52 CEST 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> _VERSION
Lua 5.4
```